# impossible to escape single quotes in XML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, escaping

please help me with this issue. I have a php file which generates XML. I have the following code that I can not escape a JS script within XML as follows:

```
$xml_after='<html>'.htmlspecialchars('    
<div class="options" id="options_'.$tables_row['id'].'">    
<a class="insidetable" href="" title="'.$lang['delete'].'" 
onClick="show_confirmation(\''.$messages['delete_table'].'\',\''.$lang['close'].'\',hide_element(\'confirmation\');\''.$lang['delete'].'\',remove_table(\''.$tables_row['id'].'\');hide_element(\'confirmation\');\');return false;\" ><img src="../images/interface/icons/delete.png" />    
</a></div>').'</html>';
```

The problem is in onclick functions..
Please help, full day losted already   , thank you

Comment: Stop trying to generate XML by mashing together strings. Use an XML library.

Comment: Looks more like HTML, XML doesn't have onclick attributes ?

Comment: XML has whatever attributes you desire. It isn't HTML (the title element is missing).

Comment: guys, I didn't attached the full code including tags, titles and etc because the error is in this fragment. After removing it the html comes and works, just a stupid single quotes escape problem.. I tried many things to escape it but no success

Comment: Generaly the problem is in show_confirmation() function because it has included 3 subfuncitons and one of them can not be escaped correct. If I only remove onclick the ajax sends correct html

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that htmlspecialchars() escapes `<` and `>`, too. You have to use it on each value separately, not on the complete html fragment.

[htmlspecialchars()](http://de.php.net/htmlspecialchars) has an option that escapes *all* quotes.

```
 var_dump(htmlspecialchars("Escaping: <>&'\"", ENT_QUOTES));
```

Ouptut:

```
string(35) "Escaping: &lt;&gt;&amp;&#039;&quot;"
```

But it would be better to use [DOM](http://de.php.net/DOM) and let it take care of the escaping.

Additionally, I suggest using data-* attributes in HTML. The Javascript can read the attributes and bind the logic to the elements. This separates the actual JS logic from the HTML.

Comment: which type quotes this escapes Thomas? Sindle or both?

Comment: Thomas, ENT_QUOTES didn't help.. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is incorrectly formatted

```
$xml_after='<html>'.htmlspecialchars('<div class="options"
     id="options_'.$tables_row['id'].'">    

<a class="insidetable" href="" title="'.$lang['delete'].'" 
     onClick="
     show_confirmation(\''.$messages['delete_table'].'\',\''.$lang['close'].'
          \', hide_element(\'confirmation\');\''.$lang['delete'].'    
          \', remove_table(\''.$tables_row['id'].'\');
              hide_element(\'confirmation
          \');
      \');return false;\" > 

<img src="../images/interface/icons/delete.png" />    

</a></div>').'</html>';
```

after each of the functions inside the `show_confirmation` functions you have a `;` which isn't valid in a function calls parameter list

On the last line of the onClick function:

```
\');\');return false;\" >
```

The second `\'` is unmatched and the double quote `\"` shouldn't be escaped as far as I can see change that and maybe it will work for you.